# Assign multiple Rigidbodies to function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, rigid-bodies

I'm working on a Unity + Vuforia app that works on a specific box of wine. there a tap on the side, when you click on it, spheres start dropping from it as if liquid. i made a script that gives gravity to a sphere at a click on the tap.

```cs
[SerializeField] 
private Rigidbody sphere;
public Collider tap;

void Start()
{
    
    tap = GetComponent<Collider>();
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (sphere.useGravity == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("Flows");
        sphere.useGravity = true;
        sphere.isKinematic = false;
    }

    else if (sphere.useGravity == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Stops");
        sphere.useGravity = false;
        sphere.isKinematic = true;
    }
}
```

A sphere is assigned to the `sphere` variable, what i want is for the inspector to have a field where i can enter how many spheres i want attached, and then attach them manually. Instead of making a variable for each of the spheres. If there is another way of doing this please let me know.

To summarize: I want several rigidbodies to `useGravity` on one click.

Comment: Why not use an array¿

Comment: @SagiZiv how do i do that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a list of rigidbodies like `public List<RigidBody> bodies`, but you need to assign all your spheres to the list using `bodies.Add(rb)` The effect you are achieving is then in the single frame where the `OnMouseDown()` function is called. It will loop through the list using `foreach`

```
[SerializeField] 
private List<Rigidbody> bodies;
public Collider tap;

void Start()
{
    tap = GetComponent<Collider>();
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (sphere.useGravity == false)
    {
        foreach (Rigidbody body in bodies)
        {
            body.useGravity = false;
            body.isKinematic = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The name 'body' does not exist in the current context

Comment: apologies my friend, I spelled Rigidbody wrong in my initial answer. But I have corrected it - foreach (Rigidbody body in bodies)

Comment: Ah thank you. I will try this later and get back to you ❤